# Laravel homestead.app not loading

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have been building web apps with Vanilla PHP for about a year now in conjunction with AJAX to make single page applications. I want to step up my knowledge a little bit and learn Laravel in the hopes of creating larger scale applications.

I know very little about Virtual Machines or ports unfortunately, and despite my best efforts reading the documentation and watching the L5 Fundamentals Laracasts, I can't set up my homestead Virtual Server.

I have installed both VirtualBox and Vagrant. I first specify my export path using:

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

because if I don't it says that homestead doesn't exist. I then startup homestead with 'homestead up' and then open SSH with 'homestead ssh'.

The terminal shows that this was completely successful, and my Terminal opens in vagrant@homestead but when I try and connect to http://homestead.app:8000 the connection times out. Below, you can find my .yaml file:

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: /Users/Liam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Any help would be appreciated. I really want to get to work with Laravel and I just don't know enough to find the solution myself.

EDIT: I should also like to add that if I try and connect to 127.0.0.1 it brings up my XAMPP directory (don't know how to get rid of this and not sure if it is cause of conflict) and if I specify port 8000 (127.0.0.1:8000) I get the message 'No input file specified'. Not sure if this helps at all. Also, I have attempted to add 192.168.10.10 homestead.app to the bottom of my hosts file and that still hasn't done anything.

Thanks guys!

Comment: can you connect to the site from the VM ? so ssh to the VM then run curl http://127.0.0.1 for example, what the output ?

Comment: I get  'No input file specified.'